# SAPUI5 Utilize full width of WizardStep

Tags: sapui5

I am using a Wizard object in my app with multiple steps. I want the content of this step to utilize the full width available. I am currently using the below XML, though this is just resulting in the content being bunched together on the left (see attached image).

How can I modify this so the SimpleForms will use the full width of the page ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

thanks,

Joe

```
  <WizardStep id="wizStep2" validated="true" title="Customer Confirm" 
    icon="sap-icon://customer" >
    <HBox width="100%" fitContainer="true">
    <form:SimpleForm editable="true">
    <Label text="Title"/>
    <Input value="MR"/>
    <Label text="Name"/>
    <Input value="John"/>
    <Input value="Smith"/>
    <Label text="House"/>
    <Input value="81"/>
    <Label text="Street"/>
    <Input value="Main Road"/>
    <Label text="City"/>
    <Input value=""/>
    <Label text="PostCode"/>
    <Input value=""/>
    </form:SimpleForm>
    <form:SimpleForm editable="true">
    <Label text="Home Tel"/>
    <Input value=""/>
    <Label text="Mobile No"/>
    <Input value=""/>
    <Label text="Email"/>
    <Input value=""/>
    </form:SimpleForm>
    </HBox>
    </WizardStep>
```

[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6PpH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `SimpleForm` will start a new column if you use a `Title` element: [Simple Form API Doc](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm). You also can control the Layout of the Simple Form by using `SimpleFormLayout`.

So basically, you need to place content that will actually **use** the 100% width.

Comment: Thanks, that has worked, I don't actually want a Title to the form but adding the Title element without any assigned text has worked nicely.

Answer (score 0):

By default it uses 100% with ... your limitation comes from somewhere else in your view.

This wizard takes 100% of your screen:

```
<mvc:View controllerName="tc_v1.test.controller.Main" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form">
    <App id="idAppControl">
        <pages>
            <Page title="{i18n>title}">
                <content>
                    <Wizard id="wizard" complete="onPressReview" finishButtonText="Review" showNextButton="true">
                        <WizardStep id="wizStep1" validated="true" title="Customer Confirm" icon="sap-icon://customer">
                            <HBox fitContainer="true">
                                <form:SimpleForm editable="true">
                                    <Label text="Title"/>
                                    <Input value="MR"/>
                                    <Label text="Name"/>
                                    <Input value="John"/>
                                    <Input value="Smith"/>
                                    <Label text="House"/>
                                    <Input value="81"/>
                                    <Label text="Street"/>
                                    <Input value="Main Road"/>
                                    <Label text="City"/>
                                    <Input value=""/>
                                    <Label text="PostCode"/>
                                    <Input value=""/>
                                </form:SimpleForm>
                                <form:SimpleForm editable="true">
                                    <Label text="Home Tel"/>
                                    <Input value=""/>
                                    <Label text="Mobile No"/>
                                    <Input value=""/>
                                    <Label text="Email"/>
                                    <Input value=""/>
                                </form:SimpleForm>
                            </HBox>
                        </WizardStep>
                        <WizardStep id="id_wizStp2" validated="true" title="Step 2"/>
                        <WizardStep id="id_wizStp3" validated="true" title="Step 3"/>
                    </Wizard>
                </content>
            </Page>
        </pages>
    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

[image: 100% width...]

Comment: Thanks, this has half worked, I created a new view with your code to check it worked, but for some reason when the view is initially loaded it is still bunched to the left, however, when I refresh the page it then uses the full width as shown in your example. Also strangely when I add the same Simple form into Step two and load the page, the step two form appears bunched together on the left, not using the full width.

Comment: provide more code from your view. maybe we can identify why. thanks.